# How to select random data from xml file using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

for example i have the following xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="examen.xsl"?>
<examen>
    <question reponse="ID1">
        <enonce>Question 1</enonce>
        <reponse id="ID1">R1</reponse>
        <reponse id="ID2">R2</reponse>
        <reponse id="ID3">R3</reponse>
        <reponse id="ID4">R4</reponse>
    </question>
    <question reponse="ID6">
        <enonce>Question 2</enonce>
        <reponse id="ID5">R1</reponse>
        <reponse id="ID6">R2</reponse>
        <reponse id="ID7">R3</reponse>
        <reponse id="ID8">R4</reponse>
    </question>
    <question reponse="ID10">
        <enonce>Question 3</enonce>
        <reponse id="ID9">R1</reponse>
        <reponse id="ID10">R2</reponse>
        <reponse id="ID11">R3</reponse>
        <reponse id="ID12">R4</reponse>
    </question>
</examen>
```

and i need to select 5 or more questions randomly using xslt

Thanks for any help ;)

Comment: How can you  select 5 or more questions from an input of 3 questions only??? In any case, there is no random functionality in XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25867727/generate-random-number-in-rss-viewer-webpart/25869149#25869149

Comment: @michael.hor257k nooo the inputs it's more than 3 but i mentioned her only 3, thank you

Comment: Well, which processor will you be using? You can generate a random number from a seed of current dateTime, if your processor supports that..

Comment: @michael.hor257k now i can generate random number between two numbers by using java.lang.math inside xslt but based on that i cant get randomly questions to now ;(

Comment: Which XSLT 2 processor do you use? Saxon is the most common and since Saxon 10 and XSLT 3 and higher-order function support it has e.g. `random-number-generator(current-dateTime())?permute(//question)[position() le 5]` so check whether you can't use Saxon HE 10 or 11 or 9.8 or 9.9 for the commercial editions.